# Listar apenas itens futuros no C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, lista, mvc

Tenho uma base de dados com uma lista de shows cadastrados com local, data e hora, porém preciso que ele me retorne na tela do administrador somente os shows que ainda vão acontecer ao invés de listar todos shows (passados e futuros), se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço!

O código está assim:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new EventosViewModel();

        foreach (var evento in _db.Evento.ToList())
        {
            List<DiaEventoAssociadoViewModel> dias = new List<DiaEventoAssociadoViewModel>();
            if (evento.Dias == null)
                evento.Dias = _db.EventoDia.Where(e => e.EventoId == evento.EventoId).ToList();

            foreach (var dia in evento.Dias)
            {
                dias.Add(new DiaEventoAssociadoViewModel
                {
                    Entrada = dia.DataHoraInicio,
                    EventoId = dia.EventoId,
                    Saida = dia.DataHoraFim,
                });
            }

            if (model.Eventos == null)
                model.Eventos = new List<EventoViewModel>();

            model.Eventos.Add(new EventoViewModel(evento)
            {
                Dias = dias
            });
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: A resposta depende do que seria um "eventos que ainda não aconteceram" para o seu negócio. Tente melhorar sua pergunta, por exemplo: "eventos que ainda não aconteceram" são eventos onde o campo Saida não está preenchido ou seja está nulo. Com esse exemplo poderemos de mostrar como adicionar esse filtro a sua consulta se for o caso. Se possível edite a pergunta e adicione essa informação :-)

Comment: Desculpe Renan... sou novo tanto aqui no Stack quanto na área.. estou aprendendo muita coisa ainda... editei a pergunta! =)

Comment: Agora sim está mais claro :-), o @Victor Laio já até respondeu aí rs. Agora você precisa aceitar a resposta se ela resolve seu problema para que a pergunta não fique em aberto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, aparentemente você quer trazer do banco todos os registros onde a Data de início do evento é maior que a data atual correto?

Basta fazer isso:

```
if (evento.Dias == null)
    evento.Dias = _db.EventoDia.Where(e => e.EventoId == evento.EventoId &&
    DataHoraInicio >= DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

Desta maneira, ele irá trazer apenas os eventos onde a `DataHoraInicio` é maior ou igual a data atual.

Comment: Suas perguntas e respostas são muito vagas amigo, infelizmente fica dificil te ajudar assim. O que exatamente não deu certo? Deu algum erro?

Comment: Deu certo sim! Muito obrigado Victor!!!